# Boost spirit calculator example run

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-construction, grammar, boost-spirit

I am a Spirit beginner and studying it nowadays. I am at [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/spirit/example/qi/calc6/) example, a simple calculator. I compiled and runned the program successfully. When run the program it says, type some statements and then type . to compile and run these statements. I type the followings in distinct runs and after each line i type a . (period).

```
2
2;
2*2
2*2;
x=2
x=2;
```

But none of them works. Everytime it says "parsing failed.". What am is missing, or is there sth wrong with the example. The example program's grammar is [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/spirit/example/qi/calc6/calc6b.hpp). Note that i am aware that i am not using the latest spirit, i use 1.46.1 version which is the default in Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have missed the fact that the program parses statements, not bare expressions, see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/spirit/example/qi/calc6/calc6c.hpp

So try this:

```
var y; 
var x = 6; 
y = 3 * x;
```

Outputs:

```
-------------------------
Parsing succeeded
-------------------------
Results------------------

    x: 6
    y: 18
-------------------------

Bye... :-)
```

Hope that helps. And ***consider upgrading boost*** - installing it from source is really simple on Debian/Ubuntus.